# Android phone contact 2.1

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number

In my application i need to show all the phone contact including contact image, currently i read all the data in to array and show ,but in some lower end phones it create problem ,like out of memory is there any alternative way to display the all the phone contact.

NB: the default phone contact intent is not my requirement , i need to get all the phone numbers, and also if first name is empty i need to show the organization name.

Answer (score 0):

For showing organization name you should try this code:

```
String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
  String[] orgWhereParams = new String[]{id, 
   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}; 
  Cursor orgCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                null, orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null);
  if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) { 
   String orgName = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA));
   String title = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));
  } 
  orgCur.close();
```

Comment: i have seen higpress, i need a way to create listview without using explicit array, by loading data in to the array create out of memory problems